# How to draw a line on an image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

If I have the polar coordinates of a line, how can I draw it on an image in OpenCV & python?

[`Line`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) function takes 2 points, but draws only the segment. I want to draw a line from one edge of the image to other.

Comment: Could you show us the code of how you have defined the line in polar coordinates?

Comment: I have theta and rho. So my line is x*cos(theta)-y*sin(theta) = rho. To be more precise, I am trying to implement Hough transform myself and want to visualize the lines from Hough space on my image.

Comment: ellipse can do arcs, if that#s what you're looking for

Comment: It's still a line, problem is mapping that line to pixels. Something that `Line` function does when you give it two points. I can calculate 2 points within the image bounds for a given equation, but I want it to extrapolate for the entire width/height of the image.

Comment: Just calculate for 2 points outside. cv's Line is fine with e.g. (-10,-10) for a point

Comment: Awesome, works! Thanks @RobertCaspary. Do you want copy that as the answer for anyone else?

Comment: Yes, its a quick and dirty solution ;-)

Comment: What I missed: `pip install opencv-python` for `cv2`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Just calculate for 2 points outside. opencv's Line is fine with e.g. (-10,-10) for a point.

```
import cv2  # python-opencv
import numpy as np

width, height = 800, 600
x1, y1 = 0, 0
x2, y2 = 200, 400
image = np.ones((height, width)) * 255

line_thickness = 2
cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), thickness=line_thickness)
```

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.line

Answer (score 20):

Take a look to the following solution, I firstly convert a line in polar equations to cartesian and then I use `numpy.vectorize()` to generate a vector that allows me to get represent the line in any point of the space.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_size = (200,200)
img = np.ones(img_size) * 255

# polar equation
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 1000)
r = 1 / (np.sin(theta) - np.cos(theta))

# polar to cartesian
def polar2cart(r, theta):
    x = r * np.cos(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    return x, y

x,y = polar2cart(r, theta)
x1, x2, y1, y2 = x[0], x[1], y[0], y[1]

# line equation y = f(X)
def line_eq(X):
    m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    return m * (X - x1) + y1

line = np.vectorize(line_eq)

x = np.arange(0, img_size[0])
y = line(x).astype(np.uint)

cv2.line(img, (x[0], y[0]), (x[-1], y[-1]), (0,0,0))
cv2.imshow("foo",img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This looks good. But I don't think you need to vectorize and calculate for the entire range. You just need to calculate for x = 0 and x = img_size[0].

Answer (score 7):

You can see how to do this in the [Hough Line Transform tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('dave.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines3.jpg',img)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to solve the problem of drawing infinite line segment in OpenCV with two given points.

```py
### function to find slope 
 def slope(p1,p2):
    x1,y1=p1
    x2,y2=p2
    if x2!=x1:
        return((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
    else:
        return 'NA'

### main function to draw lines between two points
def drawLine(image,p1,p2):
    x1,y1=p1
    x2,y2=p2
    ### finding slope
    m=slope(p1,p2)
    ### getting image shape
    h,w=image.shape[:2]

    if m!='NA':
        ### here we are essentially extending the line to x=0 and x=width
        ### and calculating the y associated with it
        ##starting point
        px=0
        py=-(x1-0)*m+y1
        ##ending point
        qx=w
        qy=-(x2-w)*m+y2
    else:
    ### if slope is zero, draw a line with x=x1 and y=0 and y=height
        px,py=x1,0
        qx,qy=x1,h
    cv2.line(image, (int(px), int(py)), (int(qx), int(qy)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    return image
```

You can use p1 and p2 according to your requirement and call the function `drawLine`.