# Extract keypoint coordinates and draw lines using cv::line

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I found [How to get pixel coordinates from Feature Matching in OpenCV Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716610/how-to-get-pixel-coordinates-from-feature-matching-in-opencv-python) to extract matched features coordinates and [How to draw a line on an image in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632276/how-to-draw-a-line-on-an-image-in-opencv?answertab=oldest#tab-top) to draw lines b/w the two points as in the attached image. I am not getting how to use this in my case.

```
    from skimage.segmentation import slic
    from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
    from skimage.util import img_as_float
    from skimage import io
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    image=cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\pragyan.prakash\\001_F.png')
    segments = slic(img_as_float(image), n_segments = 100, sigma = 5)
    fig = plt.figure("Superpixels")
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(img_as_float(cv2.cvtColor(image, 
    cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)), segments))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
    feature=[]
    # loop over the unique segment values
    for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
    # construct a mask for the segment
        mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
        mask[segments == segVal] = 255
        img=cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
        feature.append(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    orb = cv2.ORB_create()
    key=[];desc=[];sel= [];
    for i in feature:
        kp,des=orb.detectAndCompute(i,None)
        if des is not None: 
            key.append(kp)
            desc.append(des)
            sel.append(i)
    # create BFMatcher object
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    match=[];pairs = [];
    for i in range(len(desc)):
        for j in range(len(desc)):
            #print (i,j)
            if i!=j:
                match.append(bf.match(desc[i],desc[j]))
                pairs.append((i,j))
    sorted_match=[]
    for i in match:
        sorted_match.append(sorted(i,key=lambda x:x.distance))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS2tu.png)

Comment: Well, welcome. Can you be more specific of what's your actual problem is? Also do you want to match 2 different images or features in a single image?

Comment: I am trying to implement this paper https://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-68505-2_6,i want to match feature in the single image

Comment: The link seems broken. Can you check it or provide another one?

Comment: https://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-68505-2_6

Comment: Hi Eypros ,i updated the code and question,please have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55339719/how-to-apply-ransac-on-segments-and-plotting-them