# Draw the Map of the moving object using Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem where I have to track and then draw the map of the moving object. I have done the tracking part but now I am stuck on how to map the moving object where I have to draw the trajectory of that moving object on Opencv? Can you please help me?

Comment: You can use `cv::line` to draw a line over a `cv::Mat` (opencv class used for images). There are other drawing functions as well. See: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. But I think it is with C++, I am doing it with py. Is there any example that is done with py where the implementation is shown?

Comment: See examples of using opencv drawing function in python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632276/how-to-draw-a-line-on-an-image-in-opencv.

Comment: @wohlstad Thank you very much! I wish you an amazing day!

Comment: I have gotten to the point where I can perform this: 

'''
importing cv2
import cv2

path = r'test.jpeg'

image = cv2.imread(path)

window_name = 'Image'

start_point = (0, 0)

end_point = (250, 250)

color = (0, 255, 0)

thickness = 9

image = cv2.line(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)

cv2.imshow(window_name, image)
cv2.waitKey() 
'''
But I cannot see the simulation. Do you know how can I see it?